# iPad Safari: device width is device-height?

Tags: html, ios, ipad, ios4, safari

Take a look at the code below. To have the web page fill the horizontal space, I specify in the `viewport` meta tag: `width=device-height`

In landscape orientation `device-height` evaluates to 1024px, and in portrait orientation it evaluates to 768px!

I am puzzled: Why is the *width of the device* stored in `device-height`? Is this the case for all iOS devices?

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fit to Width Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-height">
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0; width: 1024px">
    <div style="width: 1022px; border: 1px solid red">
      1024px wide
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So that when the device is rotated that it doesn't end up displaying incorrectly.

Comment: That explanation doesn't make sense to me. `device-height` is *always* the width of the device, i.e. 768px in portrait orientation and 1024px in landscape orientation.